# Delphi database search

Tags: database, delphi

i m working on small app with login by mail / password 
which uses database

in database 
i have :

- client number
- client Mail
- Client Password
- Client Available credits

for login i check user mail/password in db
with this code :

```
if not (tbl1.Locate('Mail', edt1.text,[]) and tbl1.Locate('Password', edt2.text,[]) ) then
   begin
    mmo1.lines.add('Not Registered User');
   end
   else
   begin
    mmo1.lines.add('Registered User');
   end;
end;
```

this works for login 
my problem is with credits

for example 
user john have 10 credits

i cannot use locate here

**how can i get available amount of credits of john from DB ?**

thanks alot

Comment: Once you locate the record, e.g. `ShowMessage(tbl1.FieldByName('Available credits').AsString);` ?

Comment: yes what if there are 10 users with same amount of credits ?
how to show extact amount of credits ?
thx

Comment: @dudey: just an advice: insted of performing Locate twice, call it once and check the field values. Locate sets the found record as the current one, so if Locate returns True, the dataset is on the desired record. You can read the fields and test their values as you see fit. Calling Locate twice means running the search twice.

Comment: It's not what you asked, but your two Locate()s don't seem to ensure that the password belongs to the user in question.

Comment: thx alot alex for advice 
as i m noob in delphi can u please show me one example thx alot :)

Comment: @MartynA yes bro :/ any advice u got for that pls ?

Comment: Guys any one can give to advice : How to match Password with exact user mail cause this method i m using not works as @MartynA said :/

Comment: Not only that you run the search twice, you may locate the WRONG record. if You and I have the same passwords the result record is up to luck :)

Comment: yes but from code below posted by Ravault123 works perfect ;)
try and post result

Comment: If you were referring to me, I didn't said anything about Ravault123 code which should in fact locate a single record match.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use multiple fields in the locate: see [Using locate](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/Using_Locate)

```
if  (tbl1.Locate('Mail; Password', VarArrayOf([edt1.text, edt2.text]),[])) then 
begin
  mmo1.lines.add('Registered User: '+ tbl1.FieldByName('credits').asString);
end
else
begin
  mmo1.lines.add('Not Registered User');
end;
```

Comment: A short explanation would have been nice :)

Comment: work like a charm - Thx alot 
this forum is best place for new programmers like me to learn :)
Tested working 101% ;) thx Ravault123

Comment: kobik: My english is not so good to explain something. I 'm not a writter. ;-)

Comment: I've set some explanation.

Comment: one question guys as my question is still related to this thread so i will post it here -
 how can i edit credits value when anyone use it ?
i m doing it this way : tbl1.FieldByName('credits').AsInteger := +1;
but it creates new field :(

Comment: tbl1.FieldByName('credits').AsInteger := tbl1.FieldByName('credits').AsInteger +1

Comment: Don't forget the edit and the post.  tbl1.edit; tbl1.FieldByName('credits').AsInteger := tbl1.FieldByName('credits').AsInteger +1; tbl1.post;